# Does random forest ever ignore any attributes?

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest

In any possible scenario, such as:

1. If the attribute values are totally random
2. If the attribute values are all equal (like all 0)
3. If almost all attribute values are missing (or let's say all of them are missing in a hypothetical case)
4. etc.

P.S: I know that it (like any other algorithm) considers different importances for each attribute, but I'm asking if it ever decides to remove an attribute from its trees, if the attribute is a very bad one.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible that a predictor ends up not being split upon by any of the trees in the forest.  But the forest does not have the agency to ignore a feature outside of the split choosing mechanism in each individual tree.

Answer (score 0):

Random forest is an ensemble of many (weak) trees. Each tree grows independently from each other. So to answer your question, we could just use one tree.

When a tree grow, it has to select a variable to split to maximum some gain (like Gini information). If a variable is constant, or with a lot of missing values, then the variable is very much likely not to be chosen. Trees does not remove any variable but it selects informative variables. As a result, some variable probably will never be selected (thus abandoned by the algorithm).